# JSP c:import giving java.net.SocketException when using short name alias

Tags: java, jsp, iis, jboss

I have a Java web app which has a JSP page which has a couple `c:import` lines in it.  The content referenced is on the same web server as the Java app, but is not bundled in the war file.  My site has dns entries to allow for access to this app from a browser with a full name `https://abc.123.def.com/app` or a short name of just `https://abc/app` for users on our network.

If I access the jsp page via the alias `https://abc/app` I can get to the jsp page in the browser, but I get a server exception `Problem accessing the absolute URL "https://abc//webfiles/included_file.html". java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` on the page.  But, when I access the jsp page via the fqdn like `https://abc.123.def.com/app` the include works perfectly, the jsp compiles, and all is well.

If I put the address of the file to be included in my browser it works with either short name or fqdn.  So even though the error is saying the JSP can't find the file `https://abc//webfiles/included_file.html` I can plug that address in my browser and get to it fine.  That's true from my separate user machine, or from a browser on the server itself.  (Yes I see that double // there, it seems to not be a problem, it loads in the browser and loads fine as an include when using the fqdn).

I have good reason to believe the code is fine, this code worked fine on my old server which had JBoss 5.  We've moved it to JBoss 6.4 on a new server and are now encountering this alias/short name include problem. I'm thinking it's some JBoss or IIS configuration issue.  Of course we have lots of external links to this application utilizing the short name so simply using the fqdn will not work.

So IIS can serve up both the jsp via a fqdn or short name, it can also serve up the included_file path using the fqdn or short name.  But Java for some reason can't see that included_file when using the short name, only the fqdn.

I've confirmed that the DNS suffix search list in the server's ipconfig includes the domain the site is in.

I'm not a JBoss config admin, and have no experience with IIS really, just a developer of the app, but I've been thrust into JBoss config/debugging out of desperation.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you could try to use the tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/
) to view the actual network packets.

Comment: A little more information.  I did not have this short name problem before we enabled secure connection over https.  Once we added the ssl certs the short name problem appears.